# How to merge existing hourly partitions to daily partition in hive

Tags: merge, hive, partitioning, hadoop-partitioning, hive-partitions

My requirement is to merge existing hourly partitions to daily partition for all days.

My partition column is like:

```
2019_06_22_00, 2019_06_22_01, 2019_06_22_02, 2019_06_22_03..., 2019_06_22_23 => 2019_06_22
2019_06_23_00, 2019_06_23_01, 2019_06_23_02, 2019_06_23_03..., 2019_06_23_23 => 2019_06_23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to extract date from current partition column and load into new table.

Create new table:

```
create table new (
...
) 
partitioned by (partition_date date);
```

Then insert overwrite from old table:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

insert overwrite table new partition(partition_date )
select
col1,
col2,
...
coln,
--extract hours if you need this column
substr('old_partition_col',12,2) hour,
--partition column is the last one
date(concat_ws('-',substr(old_partition_col,1,4),substr(old_partition_col,6,2),substr(old_partition_col,9,2))) as partition_date 
from old_table;
```

Alternatively you can extract date using `unix_timestamp` and `from_unixtime` functions:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(old_partition_col,'yyyy_MM_dd_HH'),'yyyy-MM-dd') as partition_date
```

Then drop old table and rename new.